# Display image in div based on value in Database

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

I have been working on a project but I have reached a point where I am stuck. I have a database that contains the the working status of some mahcines. The values for the status go from 1-5. I need to be able to display a different image for each machine in a webpage based off of the value that appears in the database for that Mahcine. I am drawing a big blank on how to do this. Im using a MySQL DB and everything is written in PHP.

Basically it this. If a machine has a status value of 1 then it shows a green image. If the value is 2 then it would be yellow and so on. . .

Hope you guys can help

Comment: If any answer helped, please vote/mark it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
// your mysql select, wich contains the machine data.
$query = mysql_query("select the data about machines...");

// you iterate on the result set and fetch each row to $data
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    switch($data['machine'])
    {
        case "machine type 1": // you can put integer values here as well, like case 1:
            echo '<img src="first_machine.jpg" alt = "first machine" />'
        break;

        case "machine type 2":
            echo '<img src="second_machine.jpg" alt = "second machine" />'
        break;

        default: // undefinied
            echo '<img src = "undefinied.jpg" alt = "undefinied" />'
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I use the cases to provided the right image url to the css using the example you gave above?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the img tag, instead create a div for which you apply a style class same as the machine status value

```
  <div class="machine status<?php echo $status;?>" ></div>
```

now in your css,

```
.status1{
    background-image:url(red.jpg);
}

.status2{
    background-image:url(green.jpg);
}

.status3{
    background-image:url(jpg.jpg);
}

.machine{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

Comment: How do I get $status in your example?

Comment: i used $status for simplicity, $status is just a place holder, after your db call store the machine status that you get from mysql in this variable

Answer (score 0):

```
 Ok you can't display multiple images within a image/jpeg page...

  You're telling the browser that the page is image/jpeg (in other words, the page is     AN IMAGE) but you're echoing out multiple image data

You should rather use the gallery page to show all images like this:

<?php
// $images = result from database of all image rows
foreach ($images as $img) echo '<img src="img.php?id='.$img["id"].'">';
?>

and in img.php:

 // Load the image data for id in $_GET['id'];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $data;
```